# what is the use of client scope and authorities in oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I am new to oauth2, I was trying to implement this, I found that for clientId also, i have to supply scopes and authorities, here I got confused, shouldnt be this at user level, what is scope of user and role of user.

Answer (score 0):

Scope is another word for permission. You specify which permissions your app is requesting via `scopes`. The user is presented with this list and can deny your request. An example would be requesting the `email` scope to obtain the user's email address.

The official definition defined [here](https://oauth.net/2/scope/):

> Scope is a mechanism in OAuth 2.0 to limit an application's access to
>   a user's account. An application can request one or more scopes, this
>   information is then presented to the user in the consent screen, and
>   the access token issued to the application will be limited to the
>   scopes granted.